# How to get two key values of the configuration JSON using GetSection

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have the following JSON format in my appsetting:

```
      "AzureServiceBusTopic": {
        "TopicsToConsume": [

          {
            "SubscriptionName": "sub1",
            "TopicName": "topic1"
          },
          {
            "SubscriptionName": "sub2",
            "TopicName": "topic2"
          }
        ]

      }
```

Currently I'm getting SubscriptionName and TopicName separately:

```
var topicToConsumeConfig = this.configuration.GetSection("AzureServiceBusTopic:TopicsToConsume").GetChildren();
this.topicToConsume = topicToConsumeConfig.Select(x => x.GetSection("TopicsToConsume").Value);
this.subscriptionName = topicToConsumeConfig.Select(x => x.GetSection("SubscriptionName").Value);
```

But I need to have the first subscriptionName and topicName together, for the second one likewise.
How can I get it?

I want to get these two:

```
      [0]:  {
            "SubscriptionName": "sub1",
            "TopicName": "topic1"
          },


      [1]:  {
            "SubscriptionName": "sub2",
            "TopicName": "topic2"
          }
```

Comment: What do you mean together? Could you post the example pls?

Comment: @Serge updated my questions

Comment: I have posted an answer with a code sample of how I do it in many projects.

Comment: If you have any questions let me know

Comment: I added the missing class from my answer.  It is a very simple class. I missed it on my first edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    private static List<T> GetList<T>(IConfiguration configuration, string configSection, string keyName)
    {
        var result = new List<T>();
        configuration.GetSection($"{configSection}:{keyName}").Bind(result);
        return result;
    }
```

then you can call it like this:

```
var myListOfTopics = GetList<TopicToConsume>(this.configuration, "AzureServiceBusTopic", "TopicsToConsume");
```

Obviously you need to create a class to hold the "Topic" object like this:

```
public class TopicToConsume
{
    public string SubscriptionName { get; set; }
    public string TopicName { get; set; }
}
```

**You might need to reference nuget Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder**

which gives you access to the Bind extension method.

Also notice that because of the object is a json array [] it comes out as a a List.

But in any case with this code you can pull the whole "list of topics" in one single GetSection call

**BONUS:**

You can use the same technique to bind dictionaries. So you can really get complex with it.

I made it into a static method that can easily be turned into an extension method.

Comment: TopicToConsume is a class?

Comment: I just added the class to the answer. Sorry I missed it on the first edit. @masali